# Show 'wait' cursor while form post returns a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Spent quite some time on this forum looking at answers similar to my problem but couldn't find the one that matched my case.

I have an HTML form that I am submitting via javascript to my aspx page.

```
function Submit()
{
  document.MyFormName.action = 'StreamPDF.aspx'
  document.MyFormName.submit();
}
```

The StreamPDF.aspx returns application/pdf which presents the user with the open/save dialog. The PDF generation takes quite a while and the user needs to be presented with the 'wait' cursor. This is a simple aspx page (No MVC, no other plugins).

So my only option is to use javascript to post the data.The closest answer was [this](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx).
I took the idea from this link and just before I submit the iframe, I am setting the wait cursor. But I have no way of knowing whether the PDF came back since I can't have cookies sent to the browser. It's my limitation. So I am still at square 1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but maybe, it may help.
I recently had a similar issue and I found out the same link that you posted. In the end, I found out that doing this using javascript was not the right thing to do and that all the so-called solutions for it, are full of bad practices and other things to avoid.
If you can, just target the form to a _blank page and everything will work properly and as it's meant to be. Of course you won't have the ajax fanciness but your users won't care.

Comment: Use AJAX to submit the form, then let the server call a success function when it has finished.

Comment: @Robyflc: _blank works. But the opened window would remain open on Safari windows. That is a killer for me. Hence this problem.

Comment: @David: Trying to avoid any server side changes since there are many pages like StreamPDF. (StreamPDF1, StreamPDF2 etc.) At this point it would be hard to touch every single server page.

Comment: Didn't notice this issue with Safari. I'll take a closer look at it...

Comment: I just tested _blank on Safari 5.1.2 on Windows 7. It didn't close the newly opened window.

Answer (score 2):

can you give a try with `blockui`

http://forums.asp.net/p/1620326/4457438.aspx/1?Re+Show+wait+message+on+submit

Comment: before looking at the answer this was in my mind.. you had it. awesome +1

Comment: @kjana83: Thanks a lot. But this is the same as calling a client side function from the server to stop the 'wait' cursor.  Looking for a solution without server code changes.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts to get this working, I realized that the only non-intrusive approach to fix this is the suggestion in the link I posted.  Have the server notify the client that the file is streamed by setting a cookie which is deleted by the client script.

Thanks for all your responses.